# Enabling speedometer in Quake 3

Tags: quake-3

I have OSP installed but Quake 3 says that cg_speedometer 1 is an unknown command. Which version do I need in order to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable the speedometer in Quake 3 OSP use the speedometer option: ch_drawSpeed (defaults to 0) - displays UPS of current player (units per second).

- 0 - off (default)
- 1 - Shows in upper right under time/fps counters
- 2 - Puts a smaller, transparent readout just above your crosshair

This needs to be typed in the console, which by default can be accessed with the ~ key.

Alternatively, you can add this command to your configuration file and invoke the configuration file when launching the game with something along the lines of the following (obviously taking into consideration any other command line parameters you're already using):

```
quake3.exe +set fs_game osp +exec mycfg.cfg
```

Comment: I typed /ch_drawSpeed 1 into the console but nothing happened. No error message no speedometer. What could be the problem?

Comment: Quake 3 says i have Q3 1.32 version and I installed OSP 1.03a.

Comment: If you type it with no number, does it return the value of the current setting?

Comment: It says ch_drawspeed is 1 default is 1. I made a custom config and put it in it and ran \exec mycfg...but i can't see it.

Comment: Try it at 2, the fact that it will tell you the current value of the variable means that it *is* working, there must be something else that is hiding the value. Setting it to 2 should put it in the middle of your screen. Do you have the FPS counter on?

Comment: Even calling vid_restart doesn't seem to help. I can see the fps meter and the time only.

Comment: I tried it with 2 but no luck.

Comment: Are you using CPMA?

Comment: Nope what is CPMA?

Comment: challenge pro mode, replaced that command with the superhud.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3927/discussion-between-edem-and-ickleislands)